# how to send data to server using get request

Tags: iphone

I want to send data to server when user fill ups the from in iphone , i used

```
NSURLRequest
```

but it returns with bad url when spaces are coming in the from data 
any help please

Comment: What error messages do you get and what is your code?

Comment: http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx/xxxxxx/mobile.php?method=createOrder&sid=dfdk6figau1reagpdv9sc6po67&dnumber=ali.jamali&odate=2011-05-21&ordate=2011-05-21&oshipto=shipopingto&otype=emergency&oatype=&oref=refrence&oshipvia=Shipping via&oashipvia=&opaymentmode=Payment mode&ocomment=Comments

Comment: ERROR with theConenction Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x4b89750 {NSUnderlyingError=0x4b897e0 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}
(gdb)

Comment: HI @Programmer mind,could u please help me in solving my problem.Actually i have an application which consist similar concept like yours where i want to fill the form and send get request and save data to the server .Actually i dont know this url concept.Please help me in solving this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if what you want is just send a form over GET, a possible way is:

```
NSString* urlWithParams = @"http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx/xxxxxx/mobile.php?method=createOrder&sid=dfdk6figau1reagpdv9sc6po67&dnumber=ali.jamali&odate=2011-05-21&ordate=2011-05-21&oshipto=shipopingto&otype=emergency&oatype=&oref=refrence&oshipvia=Shipping";

NSString* escapedUrl = [urlWithParams stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

now use escapedUrl as the URL for your `NSURLRequest`.
If you need help with the request just tell me. Based on your comments, i see your problem was just the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, a couple of things.  First one: why are you using a GET?  A POST is sort of canonical for sending data, like from a form.

Second: are you converting the URL to [net form](http://www.sislands.com/coin70/week6/encoder.htm)?  That is, the non-address characters to their %-sign forms, like %20 for a space?

Comment: See the second point.  That error says the URL doesn't parse correctly.  Convert to URL encoding. http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp